# SetGravity и onDraw у TextView

Tags: android, textview

Создаю кастомную вьюху на базе TextView(рисую рамку вокруг). Для рисования использую onDraw. Все работает до тех пор, пока для экземпляра своей вьюхи не пытаюсь выполнить setSingleLine(true) совместно с setGravity(Gravity.CENTER). текст отрисовывается, как и положено, по центру, но не рисуется рамка. Если использую setLines(1) и setGravity(Gravity.CENTER), то рамка отрисовывается, но размер по вертикали уменьшается на пиксель, если текст шире размеров вьюхи.

Вопрос знатокам: почему так происходит и как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 1):

А обязательно рисовать на канвасе?
Может быть достаточно в папке drawable создать xml, вставить в него все код ниже и выставить его фоном у TextView?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Возможно, что так и проще, но вопрос-то остается открытым.